How to create and persist running number/id in an array using useState()
I'm currently learning React by creating a CRUD app and am trying useState() (haven't started looking into useEffect() or any other hooks yet). My app is a TODO list, and I want to create items with running IDs.
I have the following code:
const initialList = [
    { id: 0, title: 'Buy milk' },
];
const [list, setList] = useState(initialList);

function addTask() {
    var textInTextbox = document.getElementById('input-textbox').value;
    let nextId = 1;
    setList([...list,
    {
        id: nextId++,
        title: textInTextbox,
    }
    ]);
}

return (
    <>
        <label for="item">Type item here: </label>
        <input type='text' id="input-textbox"></input>

        <div>
            <button onClick={() => addTask()}>Add task</button>

            {list.map(item => {
                return (
                    <div>
                        {item.id} : {item.title}
                    </div>
                )
            })}

        </div>
    </>
)

When I add a task, the item title displays correctly, but the ID always remain as 1 and isn't running. Please guide me in the correct direction. Thanks!


Don't use DOM methods like getElementById() with React. Create controlled inputs backed by state instead
Since nextId is always initialised as 1 in your addTask function, that's the value you're always going to get.

You could instead maintain a ref that represents the current next ID and use that when adding tasks.
const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: 0, title: 'Buy milk' }]);
const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
const nextId = useRef(1);

function addTask() {
  setList((prev) => [...prev, { id: nextId.current title }]);
  setTitle(''); // clear the title state
  nextId.current++; // increment the sequence
}

return (
  <>
    <label htmlFor="new-task">Type item here:</label>
    <input
      id="new-task"
      value={title}
      onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
    />

    <div>
      <button onClick={addTask}>Add task</button>
      {list.map(({ id, title }) => (
        <div key={id}>
          {id} : {title}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </>
);


If to get new id by prev.length, once you will be able to remove items, you will end up with duplicate ids. better way to go is id: Math.max(...prev.map(item => item.id)) + 1

@YosefTukachinsky sure. A ref would probably be the better option

In your updated answer its still not optimal. remember the setState happen asynchroniously. thats mean if you use nextId.currentfor new state in the state state function, but update the nextId.current synchroniously, if you will do addTask(); addTask() it will first increment the id twice, then add both tasks with the same id.
Therefore I would change setList((prev) => [...prev, { id: nextId.current title }]);nextId.current++; to setList((prev) => [...prev, { id: nextId.current++, title }]); (so the  id increment as part of the state update)

You're right, I hadn't quite thought that through properly
